# Proper way to cover/replace a split view controller with a full screen window?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have an application with a split view controller, at certain points, the entire screen needs to be replaced with a single window so that the split view controller and its menus no longer appear. (For example if you want to do full screen reading of a document)

What is the best way to either cover the screen or replace it with another uiview? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want exactly what [`presentModalViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController%3aanimated%3a) will do for you. Does that not work?

Comment: It might do what I want although I cant seem to get it to work, or find much documentation on how to use it, ie this doesn't work: `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:view animated: NO];`

Comment: @Jacob: For one thing, is `view` a UIViewController? A UIView won't work.

Comment: its just a variable name, sorry for the confusion.